# What does nanotime do on MacOS?

Tags: macos, go, time, clock, microbenchmark

I am currently trying to understand how `nanotime` is implemented for MacOS in Go.

On `Linux` (see link to implementation [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/58c231f244feda52f66dd4692229f740d3c3b988/src/runtime/vdso_freebsd.go#L96)), it seems to calls `clock_gettime`.

On `Windows` (see link to implementation [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fe68ab3bcde97e3a325e4aa3c70f5f9172540453/src/runtime/os_windows.go#L326)), it seems to call `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

But I cannot find what it does on `MacOS` and what kind of equivalent system function it calls. What does it do on `MacOS`?

Note: link to the source code are very welcome.

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fe68ab3bcde97e3a325e4aa3c70f5f9172540453/src/runtime/sys_darwin.go#L171) the `nanotime` implementation for Darwin. It calls into `nanotime_trampoline`, implemented in Go assembly which in turns [seems to call](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5929ead6fbdec684c38157d45715c46107fa6ada/src/runtime/sys_darwin_amd64.s#L88) `mach_absolute_time`, [defined in macOS's libSystem](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fe68ab3bcde97e3a325e4aa3c70f5f9172540453/src/runtime/sys_darwin.go#L351)